# Extension method for nullable enum

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction, enums, nullable

I'm trying to write an *Extension method* for nullable Enums.
Like with this example:

```
// ItemType is an enum
ItemType? item;
...

item.GetDescription();
```

So I wrote this method which doesn't compile for some reason that I don't understand:

```
public static string GetDescription(this Enum? theEnum)
{
    if (theEnum == null)
        return string.Empty;

    return GetDescriptionAttribute(theEnum);
}
```

I'm getting the following error on `Enum?`:

> only non-nullable value type could be underlying of system.nullable

Why? Enum can not have the value `null`!

**Update:**

*If have lots of enums, `ItemType` is just an example of one of them.*

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`System.Enum` is a `class`, so just drop the `?` and this should work.

(By "this should work", I mean if you pass in a null-valued `ItemType?`, you'll get a `null` `Enum` in the method.)

```
public static string GetDescription(this Enum theEnum)
{
    if (theEnum == null)
        return string.Empty;
    return GetDescriptionAttribute(theEnum);
}
enum Test { blah }

Test? q = null;
q.GetDescription(); // => theEnum parameter is null
q = Test.blah;
q.GetDescription(); // => theEnum parameter is Test.blah
```

Comment: @Jacek: I was going to write that, but I tested it and it, surprisingly, works.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does this mean that `theEnum` is boxed to send here? Or in general, any method which takes an `Enum` as a parameter boxes the input? EDIT: Just whipped up a quick test and checked the IL and yup, it does.

Comment: Weird thing: it works with `Nullable<ItemType>` as well, **but I'm not getting intellisense with it**.

Comment: @gdoron I get Intellisense with both `Test?` and `Nullable<Test>` in my case. (VS2010)

Comment: @gdoron I'm getting intellisense just fine with VS2010.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair. *"It does"*, does what...? :)

Comment: @gdoron lol sorry, I meant that passing any non-nullable enumeration value will box it before passing into the method.

Comment: @Chris [A boxing conversion exists from any `enum` type to `System.Enum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664600.aspx)

Comment: When `q` is null, i am getting different results for `q.GetDescription()` and `q?.GetDescription()`. The former is as expected, but the latter is returning the description of `default(Test)`. Can anyone help explain this?

Comment: @Scott `q.GetDescription()` calls `GetDescription(q)` even if `q` is null. `q?.GetDescription()` calls `GetDescription(q)` if `q` is non-null but just returns the default value of the return type of `GetDescription` is `q` is null.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply make your extension method generic:

```
public static string GetDescription<T>(this T? theEnum) where T : struct
{ 
    if (!typeof(T).IsEnum)
        throw new Exception("Must be an enum.");

    if (theEnum == null) 
        return string.Empty; 
 
    return GetDescriptionAttribute(theEnum); 
}
```

Unfortunately, you cannot use `System.Enum` in a generic constraint, so the extension method will show for all nullable values (hence the extra check).

**EDIT:** C# 7.3 introduced new generic constraints which now allow restricting a generic argument to an enum, like so:

```
public static string GetDescription<T>(this T? theEnum) where T : Enum
{ 
    if (theEnum == null) 
        return string.Empty; 
 
    return GetDescriptionAttribute(theEnum); 
}
```

Thanks @JeppeStigNielsen for pointing that out.

Comment: This is nice because it avoids boxing. You can also say `!theEnum.HasValue` if you prefer. If anyone is interested in generic constraint to `System.Enum`, also read [Generic constraints for enums and delegates](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/09/10/generic-constraints-for-enums-and-delegates.aspx).

Comment: @LenielMaccaferri That [2009 blog post can now be seen here](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/09/10/generic-constraints-for-enums-and-delegates/). The above answer, and my comment, was from 2012. However, all this is now mostly obsolete because since C# 7.3 (from 2018) you can use `where T : struct, Enum` and that will guarantee that `T` is a value type with base class `System.Enum`.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the actual enum type in your method signature:

```
public static string GetDescription(this ItemType? theEnum)
```

`System.ValueType` and `System.Enum` are not treated as value types (only types derived from them), so they are nullable (and you don't to specify them as nullable). Try it:

```
// No errors!
ValueType v = null;
Enum e = null;
```

You could also try this signature:

```
public static string GetDescription<T>(this T? theEnum) where T: struct
```

This also allows `struct`s though, which might not be what you want. I think i remember some library that adds a type constraint of `enum` after compilation (C# doesn't allow it) though. Just need to find it...

**EDIT**: Found it:

http://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody/

Comment: If have lots of enums, `ItemType` is just an example. I was sure it's obvious, sorry.

Comment: Ohh, the second part you added answers my question, thanks. But is there a way to overcome this weird design?

Comment: You can use a generic constraint, but C# doesn't allow specifying enum as a constraint. See my edit for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe better is add extra value to your enum and call it null :)

Comment: Yeah, I agree, an Enum with one of its values "Undefined" or "Null" or something would make more sense. Or you could wrap your enum in a class and make that null if you really wanted a null value.

Comment: Huh? The exact opposite is true - only value types can be used with `Nullable<T>`. And how is `INullable` relevant?

Comment: The enum null isn't option. not in asp.net-MVC