# How can Nullable<T> use it's underlying value type extension method

Tags: c#, .net, enums, nullable

One hour ago I asked a question: [how can I write an extension method for `Enum?-Nullable<Enum>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12956916/601179)
surprisingly I got an answer telling me I can write the extension method for `Enum` and it can be used for all enums and nullable enums.

Cool, it workes, **but how?**

If I understand correctly, all enums derive from `Enum` so this why I can use this extension method in every enum I have.

But... the `ItemType?` enum, for example, isn't an enum, it's `Nullable<ItemType>`, which doesn't derives from `ItemType` nor `Enum`.
Just like `List<DataReader>` doesn't derive from `DataReader` and thus can't use `DataReader` methods, though `DataReader` is it's *Generic type*.

I know The `Nullable<T>` type has a lot of "voodoo" and syntactic sugar, is this one of them?

Comment: It's only one step along the way, but unlike the List case, there _is_ an [explicit conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131345.aspx) from Nullable<T> to T, which must help.

Comment: `I know The Nullable<T> type has a lot of "voodoo" and syntactic sugar, is this one of them?` I know that this is the case for all user defined operator overloads.  The compiler will create versions of the operator for all permutations of nullable/non-nullable versions of each operands.  It must do the same thing for extension methods, but I can't find it in the language specs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extension methods do not require the class to be /derived/, they just require a conversion to exist (more specifically: an implicit identity, reference or boxing conversion; this is §7.6.5.2 "Extension method invocations").

The conversion from `Nullable<ItemType>` to `System.Enum` is a boxing conversion; same as a conversion from `Nullable<int>` to `System.Object`.

And if you defined your own structure `struct Test : IMyInterface {}`, there would be a conversion from `Nullable<Test>` to `IMyInterface`.

Boxing conversions from nullables will return a null reference if the nullable was null; and box the nullable's value otherwise. For details see §6.1.7 "Boxing conversions" in the C# specification.

Answer (score 2):

It's more type system magic than compiler magic. Since `Enum` is a reference type this means that any value you pass in will get boxed (e.g. converted to a reference).

Now `Nullable<T>` has the special handling in the CLR that boxing it will yield wither `null` if it represents a null value or a boxed value of the inner type (`T`), but never a boxed `Nullable<T>`. Of course, the opposite is true as well; unboxing to a nullable type accepts a `null` reference.

Answer (score 1):

The extension method is translated to a static method for which the first argument is the variable on which the method was invoked.

In the Enum example, since Enum is a class (not a struct), then the extension method can accept either a concrete value of the enum (which usually is boiled down to an int), or null. therefore it works with nullable enums.

that same thing would not work for int? (Nullable).  if you create an extension method for int, you would not be able to invoke it on a Nullable (it will tell you "cannot convert instance argument type Nullable to int)